# Searching for Point of MultiLineString geometry in JSON file using OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, json

I have a json file with large geometries(MultiLineString), here I got a Point among the json layer(baseLayer).

How do I search for a Point's LineString in the layer, from which MultiLineString that Point been selected?

And how do I read a json file in OpenLayers/JavaScript?

I can project the json file in OpenLayers, but when I click the map I am getting the Point, from that Point I would like to search for its base geometry(LineString/MultiLineString)

Answer (score 3):

you can read json file in openlayers with OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON().

```
  jsLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("MyLayer", {
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
        projection: map.displayProjection,
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
            url: "jsons/roads.json",
            format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
        })
    });
```

Searching point from another layer:

```
  layer.events.on({
        "featureselected": function(e) {    
             var mlFeat = multiLayer.features // Another Layer Features
             for(var a=0; a<mlFeat.length; a++){
                   var mlGeom = mlFeat[a].geometry;
                   if(e.geometry.x == mlGeom.x || e.geometry.y == mlGeom.y){
                      alert('Your Features')
                       }
                          }             
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select/find a feature you clicked, then you can use the built in OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature.

```
var selectfeature = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(    
  <OpenLayers.Layer.Vector>
 ,{ 
    multiple: false 
   ,onSelect: function( feature )
    {
      //feature already identified to you, do not need do point run
    }
  } 
);
```